Cursor is set to the beginning of the file when a command with enabled range is executed without a range
I'm writing my own plugin and I'd like to accept ranges. If no lines are selected, then the functionality of my plugin should apply to the whole buffer. If lines are selected, then the functionality should apply to the selected lines only.
So I created the following function:
function myplugin#WhereIsMyCursor() range
  echo 'cursor is at (' . line('.') . ', ' . col('.') . ')'
endfunction

and I created the command like this (first without the -range option just to test it):
command! WhereIsMyCursor call myplugin#WhereIsMyCursor()

If I open a new vim with a document, put the cursor on line 32, column 4 and I execute :WhereIsMyCursor then I get this output: cursor is at (32, 4).
However, if I create the command like this:
command! -range=% WhereIsMyCursor <line1>,<line2>call myplugin#WhereIsMyCursor()

then I get this output cursor is at (1, 1) and the cursor jumps to the beginning of the file. If I move the cursor and select lines 32-34 and execute :'<,'>WhereIsMyCursor, then I get the output cursor is at (32, 1) and the cursor remains on line 32.
Why is the cursor being sent back to (1,1) when I execute the command without a range? What am I missing? How can I create an command that accepts ranges and no ranges?

It is not "without a range". It has the default range that you've set to 1, $.

@Matt Ah, that make sense. Is this because of -range=%? How can I have command that support both, ranges and no ranges with the same command?

I tried with command! -range without the =%, now executing :WhereIsMyCursor puts the cursor at the beginning of the line but it doesn't move it to the first line. Is it even possible for the cursor to remain in the same column?

No, the cursor is always set to the first line / first column of the range. Simply -range means .,. by default. You can't "have range" and "not to have range" at the same time.

This feels a bit like an XY problem: why do you care about the initial cursor position when applying the whole buffer? Do you need to saveview/restoreview, or is there something else? The -range does what I think you want in permitting a range but providing a default when none is given… so what’s the real question?

@Matt ok, I get it, thanks

@D.BenKnoble the reason why I care is because it's annoying that when I execute :MyCommand without a range, the cursor is moved, that breaks my flow and it annoys me. It seems I wanted to have a cake and eat it too by having a single command that handle both cases.

This question is similar to: How to restore cursor position after the document is reformatted?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@Matt I would say it's rather related, at the end of the day, I want to preserve the cursor position after my plugin changes the content. I know how to do that, in the non-range version this already works. The problem is that when the command is declared with -range and I don't explicitly pass a range to the command, the cursor was already moved before my function is called. Hence my function cannot get the original cursor position.

@Pablo The "normal" way is not to preserve anything as it's done with other ranged commands in Vim. The alternative approach is also discussed in the answer for a linked question. The last cursor position is in the jumps list where it ought to be.

@Matt ok, thanks for the tip. I will read the other thread in more detail.
